# Command system for an RTS game

Tags: c#, architecture

I'm writing an RTS game, and I want to encapsulate user actions into "commands". Commands would allow:

- sending user actions across the network to other players, so every knows what the others are doing
- recording user actions to files to enable replay functionality
- validating each action before execution to prevent (one form of) cheating
- classifying actions, for example those that only result in UI changes (move the camera), those that change the game state (move a unit), those that only the map editor can issue (change the terrain), etc.

Also they must add minimal overhead. I want to avoid using reflection because of this.
So far, the best I came up with is bad because I inevitably end up with a huge switch statement.

```
enum CommandType {
    MoveCamera,
    ChangeTerrain
}

// Base class for all commands (public fields used for brevity)
abstract class Command {
    protected Command(CommandType type) {
        Type = type;
    }
    public CommandType Type;
}

class CommandMoveCamera : Command {
    public CommandMoveCamera() : base(CommandType.MoveCamera) {}
    public int DeltaX;
    public int DeltaY;
}

class CommandChangeTerrain : Command {
    public CommandChangeTerrain() : base(CommandType.ChangeTerrain) {}
    public int NewTerrainType;
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}

class Game {
    Queue<Command> m_commands;
    void Update() {
        // Example of adding a command
        m_commands.Enqueue(new CommandMoveCamera { DeltaX = -10, DeltaY = 0 });

        // Processing commands
        while (m_commands.Count > 0) {
            var c = m_commands.Dequeue();
            switch(c.Type) {
            case CommandType.MoveCamera:
                var command = (CommandMoveCamera)c;
                MoveCamera(c.DeltaX, c.DeltaY);
                break;
            case CommandType.ChangeTerrain:
                var command = (CommandChangeTerrain)c;
                ChangeTerrain(c.X, c.Y, c.NewTerrainType);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The language is C#. My question is : what would be a way to implement this system in a way that satisfies the requirements and avoid relying on a huge switch statement to branch on each different type of command?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're simply looking for another set of eyes on your code then [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) would probably be a better home for your question, otherwise you'll need to be more specific about the problem you have with the code posted.

Comment: I'm not asking for a review of the code, the code is just there to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve. What I'm looking for is a way to design this system in a way that avoids the huge switch statement while being able to satisfy the various requirements I stated.

Comment: That is not the intention of SO. If you need someone to design your system then I'm sure there are plenty out of work software designers that would love to take your money. Seriously though, your question isn't a good fit for SO, maybe try the gaming site or a different forum.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm just asking how I can avoid having to rely on a switch statement to instantiate commands, knowing that it has to be fast, that commands have to be serializable, etc. It's a clear code question with well listed requirements.

Comment: With code that _might_ work. We aren't here to code it for you or tell you how to code it. We're here to solve programming problems. Looks like you've already found a solution...

Comment: How is this not a programming problem? How do you solve programming problems without telling how to code the solution? You're not making sense. Anyway, see HackedByChinese's answer below for an example of what I'm looking for, thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9822/discussion-between-dr-asik-and-m-babcock)

Comment: I rarely participate in chat and even less often on questions that are off topic or possibly too localized. If you feel the need to discuss the appropriatness of your question, meta is the place to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a couple of ideas. First, you could expose `On<Event>` methods for each type of command. Then add an abstract method to `Command`, like `Execute` with the parameter `Game`. Each command implementation can then call the appropriate method on `Game` (including any other logic relevant to the command). You would no longer need the enum.

The other idea is somewhat similar, but uses delegates. Define a delegate for each command type, and for each Command implementation, expose an event which uses this delegate. Then in your `Command` abstract, you can have the method `Execute`, which when implemented, raises the appropriate event. When you create each event, you simply delegate the event on `Game` to a member that will handle that command.

Comment: I'm going to go with your suggestion. It reminds me a bit of the Visitor pattern which solves the double-dispatch problem in a similar way (tell someone to call you so they call the method with the appropriate type by overloading). Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did a very similar thing for a game engine a while ago.  I actually went through a few different version, and the one I came up with was something like this.

- All commands implement the Command interface (which implies being serializable)
- All commands must be registered in the CommandRegistry, and so the CommandRegistry has a unique Id for each Command.

Then to send a command over the wire you ask the CommandRegistry to serialize it for you.  It will serialize the command and tack on its Id.  The CommandRegistry on the receiving end will read the Id, create a Command of the appropriate type and then ask it to deserialize itself from the rest of the data.

I've done this basic setup both in C++ and in Go, so I think it should work fine in C#.

Comment: What I have resembles this, but how do you create a command of the appropriate type knowing the id? So far all I can find is to build a huge, eventually unmaintainable switch statement. In C++ I could it with templates and function pointers, but I don't see how it's possible in C#.

Comment: I would use your language's reflection to do that specific part, but I don't know C# well enough to know if that is viable.  Other than reflection, the easiest thing is, when registering, just pass a function pointer to a function that creates the appropriate type and returns it as the abstract class.  The registry maintains a mapping from Id to function pointer so it can make them whenever it needs to.

Comment: Thanks Running Wild. I've thought about those two, however in C# reflection is too slow for my needs, and "function pointers" (delegates) are strongly typed so there's no way to store delegates with different signatures together, unless I use a base type (but that just pushes the problem back).